# IE8 display: none elements pushing down anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a page that's setup with an input text field hidden with "display: none" via JQuery toggle(), and an anchor tag located some distance beneath it. When I use the anchor tag, either by entering it in the url or by clicking a link referencing it, I usually expect it to take me right above where the anchor is, like this:

[working as expected http://i.snag.gy/1UavI.jpg](http://i.snag.gy/1UavI.jpg)

However, when I view it on IE8, it looks something like this:

[not working as expected http://i.snag.gy/dbyty.jpg](http://i.snag.gy/dbyty.jpg)

What I'd like to have is both the hidden input field there, and also correct anchor behavior.

When I remove the hidden input from the code, it fixed the spacing, which leads me to think that IE is taking the space used up by the hidden input into consideration where on the screen to scroll to for the anchor.

This was my best attempt to try and reproduce the issue on jsfiddle, but I unfortunately wasn't successful. I can't post the actual source code I'm seeing the error on, but I'll try to provide any additional information I can.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xynev/4/

Comment: Was the answer I provided useful? Please specify so others can benefit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what my problem was yesterday.

On IE8, if you use window.location.hash to navigate to a specific area on the screen, you have to make sure to do it AFTER all your JQuery .hide() or .toggle() calls are made. What was happening was, I was navigating to the anchor tag first, and then the hide() would occur. The hide would then reduce the amount of space on the page, thereby pulling the whole page up with it.

By simply having the page perform the hide's before the window.location.hash, I fixed my problem. I'm not quite sure why this spacing issue didn't happen on Firefox or Chrome though.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have any issues getting the anchor to work in any version of IE. I was confused however with the code you have on Fiddle as it doesn't reflect what you're actually asking.

It's difficult to answer a question without some kind of clear and concise description of the issue. Though I have constructed an answer from what you were able to convey.

If you want to toggle the text field when you click the A tag. You can use the following jQuery:

```
$('#testhide').click(function() {
   $('#hide').toggle();
});
```

testhide will be the A tag id. So:

```
 <a id="testhide" href="#anchor-here">click here</a>
```

hide is the name of the div in which the input is contained (You can call it whatever you like). So:

```
<div id="hide" style="height:90px">
    <input id="hidden" type="text"/>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Here is a link to the edited fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xynev/8/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I found what my problem was a few hours after I posted my question.  I probably should have mentioned that I was using a window.location.hash. Regardless, I posted an answer below, if anyone is curious.